# Finding a solution for a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $p$ belongs to IR, find the number of real solutions of the equation of $x^5 - 5 x = p$.
how can we solve the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. In order to not get your question downvoted, please post what you've tried and most importantly, what you don't understand.

Comment: No one can give you the exact solutions for arbitrary $p$. Where is that question from ?

Comment: Even Galois can't.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i get this question from an exam from a french university, but i think the solution would be in function of  p

Comment: @talbi i didn't even know from were to start lol

Comment: @AdibAkkari Are you sure the question is not about the *number* of solutions ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe find the number of real solutions of the equation , this is how the question is asked

Comment: @AdibAkkari Haha. This is not the same thing as "find all real solutions"... which is impossible. Please edit your question with the correct statement.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: what about Chuck Norris ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I always thought that Galois was the early version of Chuck Norris.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: :-D :-D :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

It is an easy matter to show the the polynomial has a single maximum at $(-1,4-p)$ and a single minimum $(1,-4-p)$. We have the table of variations

$$\begin{array}{}-\infty&&-1&&1&&\infty\\\hline-\infty&\nearrow&4-p&\searrow&-4-p&\nearrow&\infty\end{array}$$

From this you determine where there can be roots, depending on the values of $p$.

Comment: guys ,how do you even write these formulas and arrows and others on stack ? using word  or what ?

Comment: @AdibAkkari: the is LATEX syntax.

Comment: should downloads something or what ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Study the function $x \mapsto x^5-5x$ and apply IVT on the intervals where the function is monotonous.

Comment: thx you bro appreciate that

Comment: You are welcome